# Batch run file inside .img file

Tags: image, batch-file, menu, exe

Can help me?

In my root folder have 2 files:
-menu.bat
-apps.img

I created an IMG file with some EXE inside.
Through menu.bat intend to run these files inside the image.

its possible?

BR friends :)

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to use this site!!

Answer (score 0):

Batch can't do that.
However in another language you can load the img as a library and create a thread at your other programms starting point.

To do that you first have to find programm execution point (just open it in a debugger or try `GetProcAddress`. Then call `CreateThread` like `CreateThread(0,0,proc,0,0,0);`

Comment: @Diogo Updated my answer with more info. ;)

Comment: can be more specific? what language?

Comment: @Diogo The functions are part of the Windows API. So you can use them with any language which has access to them. I would recommend C/C++. Then you'd have to inlude Windows.h.